# Why do all Google Chrome themes involve purple on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, google-chrome

For some stange reason every theme I install on Google Chrome for Linux has a purple title bar:

[image]

Instead of looking the right way:

[image]

Comment: only for chrome ?

Comment: Doesn't purple usually have something to do with transparency?

Comment: @UK: Yep only for chrome. No other program does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reported bug which looks like it was fixed four days ago:
[Theme color variation behind tabs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28243)

There's also another issue with a [discoloured title bar when using the GTK theme](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21065) which you might want to follow too.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening On Crunchbang 9.04.01 which is built off of Ubuntu 9.04. I am on a netbook but I am pretty sure this is unrelated to user preferences. My reason for this statement is Default theme AND any theme made by an artist ( https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/index.html ) works fine. Only the alternative official Google themes create a purple overlay for the title bars.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this also.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like you've got "walnut" or some other wood theme hooked in.

Try this:

- create a new user,
- log into a new X session as them
- run chrome as them.

Is it still purple?

Hope this helps!
-pbr

Comment: I tried what you said. It was still purple. It doesn't matter what them I use (except for default which is right). What made you think using another user would fix this (I don't mean this in a smart ass way, I'm just curious)?

Comment: Oddness like this is typically caused by one of two things:  (1) per-user misconfiguration (or just plain configuration) of either X or the app itself (2) system-wide misconfiguration or deficiency/known-issue with the hardware or the X server.

Comment: Thinking back on this, I think I've seen that same thing before myself.  I found it odd and went back to the default theme.  

I'm wondering - do you have Compiz turned off?  Alex's comment about transparency may well be the key, especially since it seems to be "tinting" everything except the selected tab.  The purple color could very well be Chrome's attempt to give Compiz a transparency hint.

Comment: Yeah... the more I look at that title bar the more I'm sure it's a transparency mask.  I'll bet I had Compiz turned off on the machine where I saw this some time ago. (I'm not at home so I can't check to be sure)

Comment: I've tried it with and without Compiz turned on. The only time I have had a theme work for me was back on Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Well, I recommend submitting a bug report on this then.  Especially if it worked for you on 9.04 and stopped on 9.10

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it uses the color from System Menu::Preferences::Appearance::Theme::Customize::Colors Tab:: Selected Items (Background) ?

Comment: No if it were using that it would be black.